# How can I achieve android fab speed dial selector?

Tags: java, android, material-design, floating-action-button

I saw the guidelines over at google.com/design get updated with new resources and they added a new version of a speed dial selector. I would like to achieve a similar effect to something like this, how can it be done?

The reason I'm asking here is because there isn't much information regarding this guideline out there. Anything (resource, code or an example) is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Here is a few examples (from the official site) of what I mean.

- http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsMXoxTGZGaVp4cHc/components-buttons-fab-transition_speeddial_04_xhdpi_002.webm
- http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsNjlPU1dCUUhfWkU/components-buttons-fab-transition_speeddial_03_xhdpi_002.webm

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into the same and wrote a little library for it. Have a look here: https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial.

Comment: OP is looking for the "single sheet" kind of speed dial.